# how to Real Time update of firestore data

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a future builder which is showing list of **restaurants** inside listViewbuilder,

```
FutureBuilder(
                  future: getRestaurantsList(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: approveList.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return ListTile(
                            title: ApprovedRestaurants(documentId: approveList[index] 
  as String, Index: index ,),
                          );
                        });
                  })
```

this list view is calling **approveRestaurants** which fetch data from firestore and displays.

```
FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
    future: restaurants.doc(documentId).get(),
    builder: ((BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot){
  if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
    Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String,dynamic>;
    // print(data.values);
    return Card(
      child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 150),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.17,
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 8,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        color: Colors.white38,
                        image: DecorationImage(
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            image: AssetImage(AppImages.foodImg))),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 200,),
                  Text(data['restaurantName'], style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,fontSize: 12),),
                  SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 120,),
                  Text(data['phoneNumber'],style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11),),
                  SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 250,),
                  Text(data['email'],style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11),),
                  SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 250,),
                  Text(data['address'],style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11),),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      IconButton(onPressed: (){
                        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Restaurants").doc(documentId).update({'status' : 'Approved'});
                      }, icon: Icon(Icons.check, color: Colors.green,)),
                      IconButton(onPressed: (){
                        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Restaurants").doc(documentId).update({'status' : 'Banned'});
                      }, icon: Icon(Icons.close, color: Colors.red,)),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],

              ),
            ],
          )
      ),
    );;
  }
  return Container(
    child: AlertDialog(
      //loading dialogue here
    ),
  );
}));
```

but when i accept or remove restaurant request it does not update the view until i switch

Comment: You need to change the logic from `FutureBuilder`to `StreamBuilder`

Comment: in both places?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the [`StreamBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html) widget. Try watching [this YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WuYOGBEOEOo).

Comment: im new to flutter dont know much about it. i tried that, but im confuse now, as you can  see hierarchy is like this futureBuilder>Listview>futureBuilder. i cannot figure out how changes shall be applied.

Comment: You need to change from FutureBuilder to StreamBuilder

Comment: "tareq albeesh" said in the comments

Comment: Yes, in both places